# multiple conditions in where statement in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

A variable posted by user from ui:"_author".
it can be one name or comma seperated more names.. first one is ok but I need to deal with second scenario
_author = "Erick";// thats ok

here is fine with single name,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_author))
      {
          allQueryable = allQueryable.Where(u => u.Authors.Contains(_author));
      }
```

_author = "Erick,Jennifer,Patrick,..";//hmmm

what I tried for this case:

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_author)) 
{ 
       if (_author.Contains(',')) 
        {
        allQueryable = allQueryable.Where(u =>u.Authors.Intersect(_author.Split(',').ToArray())); 
       } 
       else 
          allQueryable = allQueryable.Where(u => u.Authors.Contains(_author));

}
```

Entity defination:

```
public class Book : EntityBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string[] Authors { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_author))`. You've excluded the "!" at the start of your condition.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: My question is how can achieve my goal the thing above not work guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to have a special case for one entry and multiple entries separated by commas, and you don't need to handle the case where the user types nothing. Replace the two nested if statements with these two lines:

```
string[] authors = _author.Replace(" ","").Split(',');
allQueryable = allQueryable.Where(u => u.Authors.Intersect(authors).Count() > 0).ToList();
```